# Blank spaces inserted into XML

Tags: xml, powershell, wmi

I'm hoping some can help me with this,

I have a powershell script that puts the logged on username via WMI formats it to trim the "domain name\" and inserts it into an xml file.

The problem is that the the Sting value seems to have a buch of spaces or carriage returns in it.
heres the code

```
$username = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username | out-string
$username.trim()

$username = $username.replace('domain\','')
$xml = new-object XML
$xml.load("C:\temp\xmlfile.xml")
$xml.usersettings.username=$username
$xml.save("C:\temp\xmlfile.xml")
```

the username element in the xml looks like this after the script is run

```
    <UserName>
realusername


</UserName>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No reason to use `Out-String`, it will only add blank lines etc.
Are you sure it didn't add even more? My `$username` returned:

```
username      
--------      
FRODE-PC\frode


#End
```

Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName`. You can drop the `$username.Trim()`-line. Ex:

```
$username = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Username
```